# Remainder of trinomial

Tags: divisibility, symmetric-polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem

What will be the remainder if I divide $(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}$ by $(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3$.
I have tried trinomial expention. But its still too big for long division. Is there a shorter method for this problem?

Comment: How do you define "remainder" for polynomials of more than one variable? What is the remainder when we divide $a^2+b^2$ by $a+b$?

Comment: Well the remainder is 0. Since (a+b)((a+b)/2 + (a-b)^2/2(a+b)) =  a^2+b^2.

Comment: ... that's like saying "the remainder of 14 divided by 5 is 0, since $5(2+4/5) = 14$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3=3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$ and
$$(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}=0$$ for $a=-b$, for $a=-c$, for $b=-c$

and $(a+b+c)^{333}-a^{333}-b^{333}-c^{333}$ is divided by $3$,

we obtain that the remainder is $0$.

Comment: Nice argument. Should be $b=-c$ instead of $b=-3$, however. 
BTW it may be interesting, and also makes the argument easier, to note that there is nothing special about the 333, but that this holds for any odd integer larger or equal to 3.

Comment: @Elmar Zander Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: Thanks Michael.

Comment: You are welcome!